# Difference between ViewState["object"] and Page.Items["object"]

Tags: asp.net

I would like to know what is the difference between ViewState["object"] and Page.Items["object"]?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Page.Items` is only used for the lifetime of the Asp.net page processing cycle. `ViewState`, however, is posted back (because its written out to the form), so it is refreshed with each new page.

Comment: oh ok tx I was mixed up I thought Page.Items was posted too on the form.